# Jquery JSON search object for key and return value

Tags: jquery, json, foreach

I don't know if this is possible or how to do it but what I want to do loop through some elements with a class, get the id and see if the value of the id is a key name in a JSON object. If it is, I want to get the corresponding value and pass it back to the elements HTML.

```
var options = {
    "test1": "something",
    "test2": "something else",
    "test3": "something amazing",
}

$('.myclass').each(function(i, val) {
    if(options.hasOwnProperty(val.id)) {
        $('#' + val.id).html(options.val);
    }
});

<p class="myclass" id="test1"></p>
<p class="myclass" id="test2"></p>
<p class="myclass" id="test3"></p>
```

The problem is with this line specifically `options.val`. I was thinking about a variable variable but don't know how to do that in javascript or looking for another way.

```
$('#' + val.id).html(options.val);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the properties of your js object, get the property name,Check the similar element exists in the UI, If yes, read the value and set to the elements inner html using `html` method.

```
  for(var propertyName in options) {

    var e =$("#"+propertyName);
    if(e.length)
    {
        e.html(options[propertyName])
    } 

  }
```

Working sample [here](http://jsbin.com/qomalecegi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Will accept as soon as I can

Comment: @AdRock Thanks !  Glad i could help